# How to capture the type of validation error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using [the jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org) and I have this code to catch a error and apply a class (*myerror*) to the field that caused the validations to fail.

I would like to extend this to capture which type of error that was captured.

Example1: if you did not fill in the field. Class1 applied (css background-color:lightRed)

Example2: format of data in field wrong. Class2 applied (css background-color:lightBlue)

> ```
> jQuery(function ($) {
>     var validator = $('#form').validate({
>         rules: {
>             ip: {
>                   required: true,
>                   ipv4: true
>             }
>         },
>         messages: {},
>         errorPlacement: function (error, element) {},
>         highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
>             $(element).addClass('myerror')
>         },
>         unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
>             $(element).removeClass('myerror')
>         }
>     }); 
>  });
> ```

Comment: I don't think that is supported out of the box by the validator framework...

Comment: @mornenel Please do not add tags into the title to keep the question clean. Please make sure you read about how to post a question here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I have added the correct tags and removed the tag from the title. You can also refer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles Hover the tags to see what they are used for.

Comment: @mornenel jquery-validate is the tag for the validation plugin

Comment: @Huangism, reading all the information at the meta thread you linked... note the part about the title becoming _"ridiculously vague"_. Not using tags in the title is not a black & white rule... it depends on the title.

Comment: @Sparky Yes I updated the title to what I thought works

Comment: @Sparky did you a look at problem? is there an out of the box solution to this?

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I've never heard of doing such a thing... having a different color depending on type of error.  I wouldn't do it.  However, I don't know of any simple solution to this.  Really, you're just tying a color (`class`) to each validation message.  So the only other thing I can think of is to set that color based on which words are contained in the pending error message.  But then you'll need to trigger that somehow.

Comment: As per OP's basic requirement, if error message contains the word "required" set color1, otherwise, set color2.

Comment: @Sparky - okay you have a point. coloring the on different errors. bad idea probably. But it would be useful to capture the error type. Like in this instance where required and ipv4 format were used. something like (error(ip.required) or error(ip.ipv4)). This way you can handle different errors differently.

Comment: In the thousands of jQuery Validate questions on SO, yours is the first I've seen that needs to capture the error type for a GUI style.  Whether there's a benefit I won't say, but there's nothing built into the plugin for doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it turns out you can... (sort-off) do it.

I used `$(element).val();` in the validation to determine if the field is blank or not.

1. If the field is blank, well then its missing.
2. If the field is filed in but triggers the validation, then it must be formatted incorrectly.

So Ive used a bubble class to display the error in a separate `div` element. Not like the traditional inline error message.

The reason for this 'madness' is because the html form is small and if you allow the error message to appear inline, it pulls the poor html form to bits. I feel there is more control doing it this way.

**VALIDATE CODE**

> ```
>             var validator = $("#storeEditFrm").validate({
>                     rules: {
>                         "store_name": "required",
>                         "street_name": "required",
>                         "suburb_name": "required",
>                         "city_name": "required",
>                         "country_name": "required",
>                         "phone": "required",
>                         "store_email": {
>                             required: true,
>                             email: true
>                         },
>                         "ip_address": {
>                             required: true,
>                             ipv4: true
>                         }
>                     },
>                     messages: {},
>                     errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
>                     highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
>
>                         $(element).prev().prev().addClass('bubble');
>                         var v = $(element).val();
>                         if(v == ''){$(element).prev().prev().html('Required field')}
>                         if(v != ''){$(element).prev().prev().html('Please check format')}
>                     },
>                     unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
>                         $(element).prev().prev().removeClass('bubble');
>                     }
>             });
> ```

Here is a fiddle, needs a bit of CSS work, but you get the idea.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nel_mo/10020cer/5/)